# SharedObject.flush() not working on android 4.2 - Adobe air CS6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I have an Air application working on iOS and android. At some time, i am saving the high score using the following line :

```
mySharedObject.data.score = score;
mySharedObject.flush();
```

This is working fine on all iOS devices, and all the android devices running Android OS 5.0 and above. I am using the AIR 23 SDK. Is there any reason why the score is not saving for those particular devices? Should i limit the Android OS capability to 5.0 and above or is there any workaround i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **EncryptedLocalStore**

```
//SET SCORE
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes("12345678");
EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("score", bytes);

//GET SCORE
var scoreValue:ByteArray = EncryptedLocalStore.getItem("score");
var score:String = scoreValue.readUTFBytes(scoreValue.length);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html

Comment: does this code also stores it in the device? as in if the user closes the app and re-open it, will he get the stored value?

Comment: Apparently after reading the adobe documentation, it does, i need to test it and get back to you, thank you for replying

Comment: Thats pretty weird i wonder if u test an older sdk if it would work. The last public update i did was in AIR 19, people email me within the app, and it attaches the shared object info. I have never seen it without data on any OS version, going all the way back to like android 2.x